# Как обновить страницу в jquery ajax запросе?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть одна кнопка или форма на которой висит обработчик и при нажатии происходит ajax запрос. При успешном выполнении я могу в success только поместить ответ в какой нибудь элемент, но не обновить саму форму, пробовал удалять весь html но все равно происходило копирование в существующие элементы. Как обновить всю форму, удалив старую или обновить какой то из элементов при успешном выполнении?

```
$( ".form-signin" ).submit(function() {
    var str = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/admin/loginform",
        data: str,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $(".container").html(html);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: если я правильно понял, вы хотите очистить форму после успешной отправки данных по AJAX ?

Comment: Нет не форму а весь html код или его часть, пусть это даже будет не форма а простая кнопка

Comment: мда.. трудно понять что вы хотите.. вы можете более чётко сказать что вы хотите сделать ? что вы понимаете  под выражением "обновить html"  ?

Comment: Форма авторизации, при отправке происходит валидация на стороне сервера и в случае ошибки выводятся надписи над полями формы. Нужно обновить весь элемент с тегом form или класс-оболочку. Сейчас же у меня получается только вставить ответ куда то, но не обновить

Comment: если весь html формы приходит обратно, то что мешает заменить `$(".container").html(html);` на `$("селектор твоей формы").html(html);`

Answer (score 0):

Как правило, вместо полной замены хтмл формы, просто очищаются и/или заполняются как надо ее поля.

Например, сброс формы

```
$(".form-signin")[0].reset();
```

очистить текстовое поле

```
$(".form-signin").find('[name=field_name]').val('');
```

для чекбоксов надо управлять атрибутом checked

```
$(".form-signin").find('[name=field_name]').removeAttr('checked');
```